# Error in Julia: "Enter arrays of length that are powers of 2 greater than 1"

Tags: julia

I tried the quantum to solve the differential equations in Julia.

Then I got the message that: "Enter arrays of length that are powers of 2 greater than 1."

Please help me to debug it.
The code that I used

```
using QuDiffEq
using OrdinaryDiffEq, Test
function f(du,u,p,t)
    for i in 1:3
        du[i] = u[i]
    end
end

u0 = [1.1,1.1,1.1]
h = 0.01
k = 5
tspan = (0.0,10.0)
prob = ODEProblem(f,u0,tspan)
qsol = solve(prob,QuLDE(k),dt = h)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QuLDE` is a fairly special method since it's built in a way that can compiler to quantum computers. As such it has a limitation that any ODE that is defined must be sized as a power of 2, as the error says. 3 is not a power of 2. You'd need to add a fake 4th ODE term here (just a constant one) in order for this to be solvable.

IIRC this comes down to a limitation of the HHL algorithm and it could be masked better in the solver but as there aren't many quantum computers around right now it hasn't been the highest priority.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your information. The code has run.

Comment: I have an additional question that may the QuLDE solve the system in the format follow: 
dx/dt = f(x,y,z)
0 = g(x,y)
0 = h(x,z)
If yes would you please provide me with any references to handle the system above?.
Thank you a lot for your time.

Comment: You mean a differential-algebraic equation? QuLDE doesn't handle DAEs at this time. You could use ModelingTooolkit.jl to transform the DAE into an ODE though.

Comment: I tried to use MTK to handle my problem (DAEs), however, the MTK needs to define all of the variables by listing them. such as @variables x(t) y(t) z(t).
If I have a list of variables how would I define it in MTK? (like x = [x1 x2 x3] and y = [y1 y2 y3 y4]).